# Property 'trimLeft' does not exist on type 'string'. Lib: ["dom", "es2018"]

Tags: typescript, tsc, ecmascript-next

I am getting this Error when running the following code

```
let foo = '  foo  '
console.log(foo.trimLeft())
//foo.trimStart() works neither
```

I know most of the solutions in the internet say, that I have to fix my `tsconfig.json` to include es20whatever.

The funny thing is, I can use es2018 stuff like Promise.prototype.finally and rest spread etc. VSCode also auto completes `trimStart()` for me which is odd, because the project and the editor should use the same `tsconfig.json`.
But this particular piece of code does not compile.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "tslint-language-service",
        "configFile": "./tslint.json"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "foo": ["projects/foo/src/public_api.ts"],
      "bar": ["projects/bar/src/public_api.ts"],
      "baz": ["dist/baz"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am running this in a monorepo angular folder (as you can see above).
Perhaps there is an issue with that, I don't know.

Comment: is it compile-time error or run-time error?

Comment: Compile time error. I can run it perfectly on the browser console

Comment: Interesting, because when I got the "Property 'trimRight' does not exist on type 'string'." error adding es2018 to the lib array was enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Include the library [`"es2019.string"`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2019.string.d.ts). Update your copy of Typescript if there is no such library. It is rather new and did not exist when this question was asked.

Answer (score 11):

Update the typescript library to "typescript": "~3.6.2". Include "es2019" in the tsconfig.json lib's array. It will work.

```
"target": "es2015",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2018",
  "es2019",
  "dom"
]
```

Comment: Interesting, because for me, adding es2018 to the lib array did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think es2018 is going to work. Try changing it to "es2016"

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "tslint-language-service",
        "configFile": "./tslint.json"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "foo": ["projects/foo/src/public_api.ts"],
      "bar": ["projects/bar/src/public_api.ts"],
      "baz": ["dist/baz"]
    }
  }
}
```